# ng-change not calling a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-change

my ng-table is being build like this

```
                    <table ng-table="storeCommandsTableParams" class="table tile">
                    <tr ng-repeat="storeCommand in $data">
                        <td>
                                <input type="checkbox" ng-change="vm.toggleCommandSelection(storeCommand)"  ng-model="vm.selectedCommands" >
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

and i have controller setup like this.

```
    var vm = this;          
    vm.selectedCommands = { };
    vm.toggleCommandSelection = function (storeCommand) {
        var idx = vm.selectedCommands.indexOf(storeCommand);
        // is currently selected
        if (idx > -1) {
            vm.selectedCommands.splice(idx, 1);
        }
            // is newly selected
        else {
            vm.selectedCommands.push(storeCommand);
        }
    };
```

what i am trying to accomplish is that when ever user clicks a check-box the respective storeCommand should be sent to a function vm.toggleCommandSelection so that i could have list of storeCommands selected. but this function is not fired.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/I2NUSEg9GtAmc2kggXzw?p=info)

Comment: looks like `vm.storeCommandsTableParams` then it would be `ng-table="vm.storeCommandsTableParams"`

Comment: table params are declared like this

 $scope.storeCommandsTableParams = new ngTableParams({
      page: 1,            // show first page
      count: 10,          // count per page
      filterDelay: 7000,
      sorting: {
       name: 'asc'
      }
     } 

they seems to be working fine.

Comment: you can just add observer to the model, that way you don't need ng-change

Answer (score 0):

Your model is not `storeCommand` but `vm.selectedCommands`. So `ng-change` won't be triggered in this case when you click on the checkbox. May be you can use `ng-click` instead.

Try this

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="vm.toggleCommandSelection($event, storeCommand)">

    var vm = this;          
    vm.selectedCommands = [];
    vm.toggleCommandSelection = function ($event, storeCommand) {
        var idx = vm.selectedCommands.indexOf(storeCommand);
        if ($event.target.checked) {
            if (idx === -1) {
               vm.selectedCommands.push(storeCommand);
            } 
        }
        else {
            if (idx > -1) {
              vm.selectedCommands.splice(idx, 1);
            } 
        }
    };
```

**Demo** 
http://plnkr.co/edit/kcW7YCWsXE8mtZoxjm1J?p=preview

Comment: i changed it to 
    <input type="checkbox" ng-change="vm.toggleCommandSelection(storeCommand)"  ng-model="storeCommand">
not working

Comment: tried ng-click not working either. 
same thing works if its just a button.

Comment: When you use `ng-click` you have to change your logic.

Comment: same result. 
it works for a simple button but not for checkbox.

Comment: setting it up in few minutes

Comment: plunker saved. please have a look.

Comment: You were not passing the event argument in the ng-click method. Try this http://plnkr.co/edit/kcW7YCWsXE8mtZoxjm1J?p=preview

Comment: still not working in my code. may be it is because i am using ng-view as it is a SPA. may be i need to use directive.

Answer (score 0):

Question is not cleared but i will suggest you to use $scope. Here i am supposing that all your data in controller is is $scope.data

In from end HTML:

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.15"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
       <table ng-table="storeCommandsTableParams" class="table tile">
                    <tr ng-repeat="category in categories">
                        <td>
                            <label class="checkbox" for="{{category.id}}">
                               <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selection.ids[category.id]" name="group" id="{{category.id}}" / >
                                {{category.name}}  
                        </td>
                    </tr>
           <pre ng-bind="selection.ids | json"></pre> 
       </table>
  </body>

</html>
```

In script in respective contrller, write:

```
   var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.categories = [ { "name": "Sport", "id": "50d5ad" } , {"name": "General", "id": "678ffr" } ];
      $scope.selection = {

    };

});
```

Hi, As i understood, i have updated my answer with dummy data. Also please find the working link for plunker here [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/US0iK5IQWXZ6RB5JC2Rs?p=preview)

Comment: he is using controllerAs syntax..which is technically right..what is the reason to use `$scope` there?

Comment: @pankajparkar There is nothing wrong in it. I have explained it using $scope. :)

Comment: i tried it already. it wasn't working. i can see that hookup with the controller is fine because everything works (function is called) when i use a button but it doesn't when i use a check-box.

Comment: Hi Ras and @pankajparkar  I have updated my answer and also added a plunker with dummy data for checkbox in repeater control. Please go through it and let me know if there is any question. And please vote up if you like it. http://plnkr.co/edit/US0iK5IQWXZ6RB5JC2Rs?p=preview    Thanks